# Portable Batch System load balancer output for one job only

Tags: linux, bash, parallel-processing, cluster-computing

I am using a cluster that uses the job management software [Portable Batch System(PBS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Batch_System) on Linux and submit my jobs as per the following

```
qsub script.sh
```

where typically my `script.sh` is of the following form, for example, when running a job with R

```
#!/bin/bash

#PBS -N jobName
#PBS -o output-log
#PBS -e error-log
#PBS -t 1-10
#PBS -l walltime=12:00:00
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=16
#PBS -S /bin/bash


#Early out if non zero exit status.
set -e

if [ -n "${1}" ]; then
    echo "${1}"
    PBS_ARRAYID=${1}
fi

i=${PBS_ARRAYID}

module add languages/R-3.3.1-ATLAS

R --no-save --args ${i} < ~/some_statistics.R
```

However, it is not clear how one would generate output logs with

```
#PBS -o output-log
```

for only one instance of the job. For example, only output for the first job, when `i=1`

I have looked at the manuals provided by my instituition, but unfortunately it is still not clear.

I have considered inserting a conditional to the above submission script to delete the output log if it is not needed, however as these jobs are likely to run in parallel and take approximately constant time, it does not solve the problem of disk quota usage whilst the jobs are running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To discard the logs for all but one process:

```
if [ $i -eq 1 ]; then
    R --no-save --args ${i} < ~/some_statistics.R
else
    R --no-save --args ${i} < ~/some_statistics.R >/dev/null
fi
```

Basically, redirect the output to nowhere when `$i` is not 1.

Comment: Thank you for that. Apologies, but I'm new to this and just wanted to check would the above remove just the additional output-log files e.g. output-log-2 etc and not anything else?

Comment: Try it.  It doesn't "remove" anything--it simply discards the output of your R script before it gets written to the files.